# Invoke-SqlCmd got 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON' error after Enter-PSSession?

Tags: sql-server, windows, powershell

I ran the following query on `RemoteServer` after `enter-pssesion` from my PC `ClientPC`. (I need to use Windows integrate security)

```
Enter-PSSesion RemoteServer # from ClientPC
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance sqlserver 'select 1 a' # in the ps session of RemoteServer
```

and it got the error of

> Invoke-Sqlcmd : Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.

Then I did the following steps.

On `RemoteServer`,

```
Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role server
```

it returns

```
CredSSP Authentication Configuration for WS-Management
CredSSP authentication allows the server to accept user credentials from a remote computer. If you enable CredSSP
authentication on the server, the server will have access to the user name and password of the client computer if the
client computer sends them. For more information, see the Enable-WSManCredSSP Help topic.
Do you want to enable CredSSP authentication?
[Y] Yes  [N] No  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"):


cfg               : http://schemas.microsoft.com/wbem/wsman/1/config/service/auth
lang              : en-US
Basic             : false
Kerberos          : true
Negotiate         : true
Certificate       : false
CredSSP           : true
CbtHardeningLevel : Relaxed
```

On my PC `ClientPC`.

```
PS C:\> Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role client -DelegateComputer *

CredSSP Authentication Configuration for WS-Management
CredSSP authentication allows the user credentials on this computer to be sent to a remote computer. If you use CredSSP
 authentication for a connection to a malicious or compromised computer, that computer will have access to your user
name and password. For more information, see the Enable-WSManCredSSP Help topic.
Do you want to enable CredSSP authentication?
[Y] Yes  [N] No  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"):


cfg         : http://schemas.microsoft.com/wbem/wsman/1/config/client/auth
lang        : en-US
Basic       : true
Digest      : true
Kerberos    : true
Negotiate   : true
Certificate : true
CredSSP     : true
```

But I still got the error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If CredSSP is enabled on both the client and server (necessary for this double hop authentication), you have to simply explicitly specify the authentication as CredSSP because it won't connect with it by default.

```
Enter-PSSession RemoteServer -Authentication Credssp -Credential (Get-Credential)
```